# Button Click Event not Passing input String to MVC Controller Method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following view HTML

```
<input id="txt" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">Upload</button>
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var txtVal = $("#txt").val();
        window.location = "@Url.Action("Upload", "Tools")" + "/" + txtVal;
    });
</script>
```

My controller method is

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string fileName)
{
    string path = @"C:\GambitTests\blue-g-logo.jpg";
    // Do stuff.
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tools");
}
```

this method fires but I am not getting the text from the input box and `fileName` is `null`.

**What am I doing wrong here how can I pass the text from the input control to this method?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This presumes you have route "{controller}/{action}/{fileName}". Do you? If you don't, you could define one, or much better just use `"@Url.Action("Upload", "Tools")" + "?fileName=" + txtVal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default syntax for passing parameters in the query string is ?paramName=value, so in your case you'd need to change your JavaScript to:

```
window.location = "@Url.Action("Upload", "Tools")" + "?fileName=" + txtVal;
```

Alternatively, change the parameter name to id and it'll work as you expect (courtesy of the default RouteConfig).

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I like the sound of using the `id` but I am new to JQuery so could you elaborate?

Comment: All you'd have to do it change your method signature in your controller to public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string id)

Comment: This has not worked for some reason. I am still getting null passed to the controller method?

Comment: Using id or using ?fileName?

Comment: You need to remove the leading forward slash - ...` + "?fileName=" + txtVal;`